# How to store a compiled script name and execute it?(GCC)

Tags: linux, shell, gcc

I am trying to make a shortcut code with gcc. The purpose is to compile and then automatically execute the compiled file.The code I am using looks like this,

```
gcc $@.c -o $@
./$@
```

But it won't execute as purposed. It is saying something like Segmentation Fault.
How should I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `$@` instead of `$1`? The way you've written the script, it won't work with multiple arguments.

Comment: @Barmar `$@` could make sense in the context of a `Makefile`. Still, not enough information given here to figure out what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probly want

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if ! test $# -gt 0 -a -f "$1"; then
  echo >&2 "Usage: $(basename $0) FILE [ARG]..."
  exit 1
fi

F="$1"
shift

X=$(echo "$F" | sed 's/\.[^.]\+//')

gcc "$F" -o "$X" "$@"
./"$X"
```

Comment: Put `$@` in double quotes

Comment: @Barmar Done. I didn't bother in the first place, given that original code had much more serious problems.